# Exploiting c - linux setuid and system commands

Tags: c, linux, security, buffer-overflow

I have the following code as an executable that I want to exploit for a course in order to spawn a shell with elevated privileges. I am a user of levelX and the executable has setgid of levelX+1. I am not allowed to alter any of the code.
As I do not have root privileges, setguid(0) fails. I was not able to change the return address of the function or main function. Could anyone point to the right direction?

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (exec(argv[1]) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute your command\n");
      return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}

int exec(char *command)
{
  FILE *f = NULL;
  char entry[64];
  char line[256];

  f = fopen("log", "a");
  if (f == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
      return -1;
    }
  snprintf(entry, 64, "%d: %s\n", getuid(), command);

  fprintf(f, entry, NULL);
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen("sudoers", "r");
  if (f == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open\n");
      return -1;
    }

  while(fgets(line, 256, f) != NULL)
    {
      if (atoi(line) == getuid())
        {
          if (setuid(0) == 0) {
            system(command);
          } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "check permissions\n");
          }

          fclose(f);
          return 0;
        }
    }
  fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
  fclose(f);
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Post complete code with appropriate headers.

Comment: This looks like you have partially sanitized/anonymized the code, or tried to? Please provide a working code, which you can build yourself. For example, what is `log_entry`?

Comment: Both correct! Edited the code. It compiles and runs

Comment: What do you exactly mean with LevelX and LevelX+1.  What's the role of levels in your explanation?  In plain UNIX, there's only two levels, user and root level, the first is subject to permissions, the later isn't.  Not n levels up, sorry.

Comment: I mean different levels without any of the levels being root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it was a format string exploit on `fprintf(f, entry, NULL);` inside `int exec(char *command)` where you overwrite the return address with %n format.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted, it appears you are supposed to write your own `sudoers` file to any directory you have write access to, then run this program in that directory, so it reads your file.

So, simply write your own UID to this fake `sudoers` file, and then give a command parameter such as `bash` to get a shell. There's no need to do any buffer overflow exploitation.

Presumably the real exploitable program has suid bit set in the file permissions, so it can perform the `setuid(0)` call. I guess the purpose of the exercise is to demonstrate how *all* input needs to be sanitized when you are dealing with suid programs, including things like relative paths (which effectively take current working directory as input) like any user-supplied paths and other input.

---

But, since the program only has setgid bit (as said in comment), you need find something you do with just the group id. That something could be that log file write. You could create a symbolic link with file name `log`, pointing to whatever file you want to append to, which that group has write permissions for. Also, that file needs to have format such, that the log line format does not make the file corrupted. Remember, you can put newlines etc into command line arguments!

Comment: I did create a file with my guid and bypassed this check. The exploitable program has sgid: -rwxr-sr-x but the file's group is not the root

Comment: Ah, then you need a way to make something happen before `setuid` call... Hint: you program writes to a log with the group of the binary... That's what you are supposed to exploit then, probably.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I rushed-answered.I immediately thought I could go and maybe manage to overwrite the sudoers file or the /etc/passwd by creating the symlink as suggested and of course I cannot.

Comment: Feel free to uncheck the "accepted answer". If there's a reason to do that, that's perfectly acceptable at SO (as well as switching the accepted answer if you feel a new answer really is better than what you accepted earlier).

Comment: If you have trouble finding possible exploitable files, checkout out `find` command, it has option to search for files with certain group.

Comment: No the answer is spot on! I just have to think more

Comment: @NotApplicable: Since the program does not work for anyone as intended (unless the executable group is root), I suspect the solution sought after is much simpler than you're thinking:  it is probably just `ln -s sudoers log && /path/to/that/executable bash`, to give you the privileged shell based on a sudoers file under your own control; even if it is privileged by default, having the log output directed to the sudoers ensures the current uid will be listed there.  You could ask your lecturer whether the group ownership of the executable is as designed, or just an oversight.